# The rotation speed of the sun's equator in degrees per second

Tags: the-sun, rotation

I'm just looking for a °/s speed of the suns equator. I'm coding a sun in unreal engine, so I'm looking for its equator speed. I've seen two incorrect posts using different speeds per day, and I'm too lazy to do geometry.

Comment: Seems a fair question to ask. Whoever's downvoting, explain why? If you personally find no value in the question, try to imagine that others might benefit from it?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this is probably better suited to [astronomy.se].

Comment: If you want to have this kind of precision in your simulation, the equatorial speed won't help much, you'd need the speed at every latitude...

Comment: This is literally asking us to divide 360 by the amount of time per revolution. This question is better suited to Google Calculator than Stack Exchange.

Comment: I've voted to close as off-topic here in Space Exploration SE. The question is purely about Astronomy and has no specific space exploration aspects. You are in luck however because there is also Astronomy SE and this is on-topic there. I recommend that you remove the "too lazy" comment and instead say that you understand that different latitudes of the Sun's surface rotate at different speeds, and you'd like to understand how the rotational speed varies with latitude.  *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: Also, if you've seen two incorrect posts; 1) How do you know they are both incorrect if you don't know the answer? 2) Please add links to those posts within your question, it's possible that you are misunderstanding them and perhaps they need to be edited for accuracy!

Answer (score 5):

The Sun is a large ball of plasma and does not rotate at a uniform speed. It rotates fastest at the equator, where it takes 24.47 days to make one revolution and up to 38 days at the poles. It takes an average of 28 days to do one rotation [1].

You can calculate the rotation rate of the Sun vs latitude with the following equation [2]:

$$\omega=A+B \sin ^{2}(\varphi)+C \sin ^{4}(\varphi)$$

Where:

- $A$ is the equatorial (and maximum) sidereal rotation rate of the sun: $14.713 \pm 0.0491 ^{\circ}/\text{day}$
- $B$ is the second order differential rotation rate of the sun: $ -2.396 \pm 0.188 ^{\circ}/\text{day}$
- $C$ is the fourth order differential rotation rate of the sun: $ -1.787 \pm 0.253 ^{\circ}/\text{day}$
- $\varphi$ is the solar latitude (from -90 to 90 deg)

Below is a plot of rotation speed in $^{\circ}/\text{day}$ vs latitude:
[image: Solar rotation speed]

References:

[1] [Wikipedia, Solar rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_rotation)

[2] [Snodgrass, H. B., & Ulrich, R. K. (1990). Rotation of Doppler features in the solar photosphere. The Astrophysical Journal, 351, 309. https://doi.org/10.1086/168467](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1990ApJ...351..309S)